# Using threshold and bias at the same time in NN

Tags: neural-networks, bias, activation-function

I'm using NN with sigmoid binary activation. And for threshold I using 0,5. So if output < 0,5, it classified as 0. And if output >= 0,5 it classified as 1. But I'm using bias too at the same time. Is it ok? Cause from what I know bias change threshold into 0.

Answer (score 2):

The bias is added before the activation, i.e. $y=\sigma(wx+b)$, so that's not directly associated with what you choose as threshold.

In addition, instead of thresholding your output, you might also consider probabilistic scoring rules like ROC AUC. A starting point might be [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models) thread.